# R histogram with numbers under bars

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I had some problems while trying to plot a histogram to show the frequency of every value while plotting the value as well. For example, suppose I use the following code:

```
x <- sample(1:10,1000,replace=T)
hist(x,label=TRUE)
```

The result is a plot with labels over the bar, but merging the frequencies of 1 and 2 in a single bar.
Apart from separate this bar in two others for 1 and 2, I also need to put the values under each bar.
For example, with the code above I would have the number 10 under the tick at the right margin of its bar, and I needed to plot the values right under the bars.

Is there any way to do both in a single histogram with hist function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `hist` silently returns information you can use to modify the plot.  You can pull out the midpoints and the heights and use that information to put the labels where you want them.  You can use the `pos` argument in `text` to specify where the label should be in relation to the point (thanks @rawr)

```
x <- sample(1:10,1000,replace=T)

## Histogram
info <- hist(x, breaks = 0:10)
with(info, text(mids, counts, labels=counts, pos=1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll spend some time reading about this on R help page. :)